# Lyrics extractor (speech recognition) from a song

Tags: music, speech-recognition

I have some songs in English that do not have published lyrics due to those are not popular.
So I'm looking for an online service or a standalone app that can extract (recognize) lyrics (as text) from a song (say, mp3).

Comment: I don't think that speech synthesis is at that advanced level yet, especially when there are other sounds (like music) involved. Try uploading the file to YouTube and take a look at the closed captions to get an idea

Comment: Keep in mind that it is impossible to get 100% accuracy in this as in singing things like rhythm and amount of syllables are often more important than "correct" words. So, words will be cut of or at a grammatically incorrect place or intentionally misspoken to add multiple meanings etc. understanding art is something computers perform horribly at.